# Feign Client ignoring request params

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I created `Feign Client`:

```
@FeignClient(name = "yandex",url="${yandex.ribbon.listOfServers}")
public interface YandexMapsRestApiServiceClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "{geoParam}")
    String  getCountryInfo(@Param("geoParam") String geoParam);
}
```

In controller I have been wrote:

```
@Autowired
private YandexMapsRestApiServiceClient client;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test() {
   return  client.getCountryInfo("Moscow");
}
```

My `Applicaton.yml` look this:

```
yandex:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=
    ConnectTimeout: 20000
    ReadTimeout: 20000
    IsSecure: true
hystrix.command.default.execution:
  timeout.enabled: true
  isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 50000
```

When I try to get some result, in return I get 404 error:

```
feign.FeignException: status 404 reading YandexMapsRestApiServiceClient#getCountryInfo(String); content:
```

In this case, I see in the debugger that he `feign` not set my `geoParam`:

[image]

Why does this happen and how to solve this problem?

Comment: try to use *@RequestParam* instead of *@Param*

Answer (score 1):

As [Musaddique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5268867/musaddique) has stated, you are mixing `Feign` and `Spring` annotations.  When using `Spring Cloud Feign`(OpenFeign), you must use the Spring annotation `RequestParam`.  `Feign` annotations will not be processed.

### Update

To achieve what you are looking for, you will need to change your configuration.  The of `url` should be a url or service name only.  Using query string or other extensions to the url will have unexpected results.

Move the path information to the `RequestMapping` annotation and specify the query parameter there.

```java
@FeignClient(name = "yandex", url="${yandex.ribbon.listOfServers}")
public interface YandexMapsRestApiServiceClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/1.x?format=json&geocode={geoParam}")
    String getCountryInfo(@RequestParam("geoParam") String geoParam);
}
```

Where your ribbon configuration looks like this:

```yaml
yandex:
  ribbon:
     listOfServers: "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru"
     ConnectTimeout: 20000
     ReadTimeout: 20000
     IsSecure: true
```

Now, using your example of `client.getCountryInfo("moscow")` will result in the final url of `https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x?format=json&geocode=moscow`.

Comment: I'm using all Spring annotations and still having this issue of request parameters not sending; any other ideas?